# WSO2 API Manager database backup

Tags: database, wso2, api-manager

Is there a simple way to create a backup and do a restore of the API Manager database?  Is this supported from the API Manager UI?

Comment: Is it possible to do the backup of all configurations in /carbon and Publisher and Developer portal too? Its 2023 now, any idea if there are updates? @Athiththan

Answer (score 0):

From the UI it is not supported. you should use a migration script/backup tool, but it is not publicly available   as far as i know.  You may try to copy  DB folder to another instance..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WSO2 is not supporting for that feature currently. Usually, WSO2 product users manually creating a backup job (Such as scedules task [1]) periodically to get backups.

[1] http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/